# Xamarin forms listview items not fully shown

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this Xamarin listview:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
    <StackLayout Padding="20,20,20,20">
            <Grid>
                <StackLayout Margin="10">
                    <Label Text="Quoting and Tankering" Style="{DynamicResource TitleStyle}" Margin="0, 20" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
                    <Label Text="Select Aircraft:" />
                    <Picker Margin="30, 0, 0, 30" x:Name="pickerAircraft" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding TailNumber}" SelectedItem="{Binding Id}" SelectedIndexChanged="PickerAircraft_SelectedIndexChanged" Title="Aircraft Selector"></Picker>
                    <Button Text="Add Leg" Margin="10,10,10,10" TextColor="Green" Clicked="Button_Clicked_1" />
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding .}" VerticalOptions="Center">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <StackLayout Padding="10,10,10,10"  HeightRequest="100">
                                        <Label Text="Leg" />
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HeightRequest="100">
                                            <Entry x:Name="txtICAO" WidthRequest="30" Text="{Binding ICAO}" />
                                            <Button Text="Delete" WidthRequest="50" Clicked="Button_Clicked_2" x:Name="btn_Delete_Item_In_Cart" />
                                        </StackLayout>

                                    </StackLayout>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                    <Button Text="Go to Step 2"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Now, when I'm rendering the page the listview items are partially shown, please check the screenshot:

[image]

What am I doing wrong with the listview? Do I need to add some margin/padding in order to have the full size shown?

Also the button below the listview is not shown.

Comment: Try settings `HasUnevenRows=True`

Comment: Also, having a listview inside a scrollview is a bad idea!

Comment: @shanranm can you please elaborate why having a listview inside a scrollview is a bad idea? And yes that option HasUnevenRows equals true seems to fix the issue. Thx

Comment: It produces two scrolls, one from scrollview and one for listview, which causes may problems in page behavior as well as sizing. Don't have any links to support, but just telling out of experience. Looking at your xaml i dont think outer scrollview, grid and stack are necessary

Comment: the scrollview, outer stacklayout, and grid all appear to be unnecessary in this scenario